# TFS Build dropping extra files including csproj in target folder

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild

I have an automated build process set up to run from a build definition in TFS, which publishes a web application and generates/executes a database project script successfully via publish profiles that are passed as msbuild arguments in the build process definition.  Everything is now running as expected except that several unnecessary files are being deployed to the target folder, including the .csproj file, all of the config transforms, and the properties folder which contains all of my publish profiles.

This is strange because 1. It's definitely not including ALL files/folders and mostly appears to be including ones used by the publish profile like transforms, while applying the transform correctly and excluding any explicitly excluded file (as defined in the pubxml), and 2. The process works perfectly if I do it by publishing from the project in Visual Studio 2013.  I have the profile configured to only include files needed by the application, and I've confirmed in the csproj file that this property is there.

I tried excluding the properties folder from deployment in the pubxml file, but this causes the build to crash because it can't find the assembly file.  What I've gathered is that the process is keeping all files it needs to complete the build, and dropping all of those files in my destination folder.  FWIW, I'm using the "file system" method and I'm not sure yet if web deploy will make a difference.  I haven't been able yet to connect to the target server with web deploy, but that's a separate problem to solve.  Is there something in the build that I can configure so that my destination folder has only the files it needs to run the application, and not the files needed to BUILD the application?

FYI I also have not been using a drop folder, I'm not sure if that makes a difference or not but that might be the only thing I haven't tested as it doesn't seem necessary since I'm using a publishprofile and don't want to use the default tfs build configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works well enough, after reading this: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/excluding-files-and-folders-from-deployment
This was a little uglier solution than I wanted, since it requires hard-coding the names of excluded files, but it does the trick and only requires identifying the files and folders in one location instead of altering a publish profile for each target environment.  I created a wpp.targets file and used the ExcludeFromPackageFolders and ExcludeFromPackageFiles elements to identify the extra files.  Ironically, if I don't also name the wpp.targets file in the exclude element, THAT file is included in my package.  It's possible MSDeploy doesn't have the same issues with TFS as filesystem, but after spending half a day trying to work through a different set of issues and permissions workarounds, we decided that file system is a cleaner publishing method.